# IIS not responding for WEB API

Tags: rest, iis

I have hosted number of REST API in my IIS in single pool, its working fine, but some times, i will find one of those rest api are not working, its saying 404 error, initially I thought its happening because of some IIS issue, so I kept one test.html file in the same directory, now whenever api stops responding, I browse test.html file and that shows the content properly. So its not because of IIS i guess.

test.html is responding but my REST APi is still showing 404 error, why this is happening, anyone have any idea, any suggestion, any best practice.